# mac OS/iOS FindMy URL scheme: Possible to open a specific person/device/item directly?

Tags: macos, ios, url, find-my, airtag

Using the URL schemes

- `findmy://friend` or `friends`
- `findmy://devices`
- `findmy://items`

opens the FindMy.app with the respective tab.

But has anyone figured out whether it's possible to also activate/mark a specific item (say: a particular AirTag) directly in the list of items via URL scheme, something like `findmy://items?MyBicycleAirTag`?